# How can I add fields to a CSV based off of matching fields between two separate CSVs?

Tags: csv, powershell, logging

I am attempting to match URLs from one log file containing the URL and IP addresses to another file that only contains the IP addresses. An example log from each file looks like this:

File Containing URLs:

```
Date;Time;Source;Destination;Port;User;URL
3/7/2016;0:00:07;168.254.25.6;10.0.1.27;80;jsmith;abcnet
```

File to add URLs to:

```
Date;Time;Source;Destination;Port;User;URL
3/7/2016;0:00:09;168.254.25.6;10.0.1.27;80;;
```

I am attempting to write a script to determine if the destination field is identical for any logs between the two files, and if it is, assign the value for the URL to that IP address in the log that is missing the URLs. I have written the following two scripts to attempt to do this. The first finds all of the mappings of URLs to IP addresses, while the second is supposed to use this list to populate the URL field. However, I get a blank output for the first script, so I cannot even use the results to test the second one.

Code to map each IP address to a URL:

```
$urlMissing  = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\firstLog.csv -Delimiter ';' |
               Select-Object -Unique Destination
$urlExisting = Import-Csv C:\path\to\SecondLog.csv -Delimiter ';' |
               Select-Object Destination, URL
$result      = "C:\path\to\result.csv"

if (Test-Path $result) {
    Remove-Item $result
}

$urlMissing | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name URL -Value $null

foreach ($line in $urlMissing) {
    $cpDest = $line.Destination
    $returnRecords = $urlExisting | Where-Object {$_.Destination -eq $cpDest}

    $destURL = $returnRecords.URL | Select-Object -Unique

    if ($destURL -ne $null) {
        if ($destURL.Count -gt 1) {
            $destURL = $destURL -join ';'
        }
    }
    $line.URL = $destURL
}

$urlMissing | Export-Csv $result
```

Code to add results of first script to log file that is missing URLs:

```
$missingURL = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\missingURL.csv
$result     = "C:\Path\to\result.csv"
$urlsFound  = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\result.csv

if (Test-Path $result) {
    Remove-Item $result
}

foreach ($line in $missingURL) {
    $cpDest = $line.Destination

    $returnRecords = $urlsFound | Where-Object {$_.Destination -eq $cpDest}

    if ($cpDest -eq $returnRecords.Destination) {
        $line.URL = $returnRecords.URL
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a rough idea what you are trying to do, but your question could benefit from some clarification and consistency in what you are referring to. You list 2 csv samples, but your code seems to refer to them backwards as "First" example is not missing data, but `$urlMissing = Import-Csv C:\Path\to\firstLog.csv`?  Also unsure why your Select-Object is only selecting Destination and not * or "Destination, URL".

Answer (score 1):

First create a mapping of destination IP addresses to URLs from the CSV containing URLs:

```
$urlmap = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\SecondLog.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
  Group-Object Destination |
  ForEach-Object { $urlmap[$_.Name] = @($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand URL) }
```

Then add the URLs to the file where they're missing:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Path\to\firstLog.csv' -Delimiter ';'
foreach ($record in $csv) {
  if ($urlmap.Contains($record.Destination)) {
    $record.URL = $urlmap[$record.Destination] -join ';'
  }
}
$csv | Export-Csv 'C:\Path\to\firstLog.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

Comment: Might be simpler to create the hashtable, and then replace the URL property on the fly... `$csv=import-csv $path -Del ';' ; $csv|Select *,@{l='URL';e={$urlmap[$_.Destination]}} -Exclude URL | Export-CSV $outpath -Del ';' -NoType`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I had considered that first, but thought the `foreach`/`if`combination was more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It should do what you need if I understood you correctly. If not, it'll get you real close.

```
$noUrlFilePath = 'C:\NoUrls.txt'
$urlFilePath = 'C:\Urls.txt'

$noUrlRows = Import-Csv -Path $noUrlFilePath -Delimiter ';'
$urlRows = Import-Csv -Path $urlRows -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($urlRow in $urlRows) {
    foreach ($noUrlRow in $noUrlRows) {
        if ($urlRow.Destination -eq $noUrlRow.Destination) {
            $noUrlRow.URL = $urlRow.URL
        }
    }
}

$noUrlRows | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\FinishedLog.txt' -Delimiter ';'
```